# To know list of users having access to Views

Tags: oracle

Please help me to find out the list of users who are having access to particular user defined views in Oracle.?

Answer (score 0):

`DBA_TAB_PRIVS` is probably the best starting place. In that view, you can pass in the view you're looking for in the `TABLE_NAME` field. If you want to see who has permissions to more than one view, you could always use a sub-select on the `DBA_VIEWS` view to then see what the `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` on that view are.

However, depending on how your database was implemented, you may also need to look at role information. Using `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` may only show you the roles that have select on the view(s), from there you'll have to use the `DBA_ROLE_*` series of views to determine which physical users have been assigned those roles.

Answer (score -1):

use this view  desc dba_tab_privs;

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Explain how that view can be used.